# How to create a table/dataframe/list from part of a text file in Python?

Tags: python, text

I have a text file with the following structure:

I want to create a table of only the 'StructName' and the 'Volume_mm3' header in Python, but I am not sure how to do this. The information in the rows with # TableCol, # NRows and # NTableCols are not necessary. Does anyone have any suggestions for me? Thanks in advance!

```
# TableCol  1 ColHeader Index 
# TableCol  1 FieldName Index 
# TableCol  1 Units     NA 
# TableCol  2 ColHeader SegId 
# TableCol  2 FieldName Segmentation Id
# TableCol  2 Units     NA
# TableCol  3 ColHeader NVoxels 
# TableCol  3 FieldName Number of Voxels
# TableCol  3 Units     unitless
# TableCol  4 ColHeader Volume_mm3
# TableCol  4 FieldName Volume
# TableCol  4 Units     mm^3
# TableCol  5 ColHeader StructName
# TableCol  5 FieldName Structure Name
# TableCol  5 Units     NA
# TableCol  6 ColHeader normMean 
# TableCol  6 FieldName Intensity normMean
# TableCol  6 Units     MR
# TableCol  7 ColHeader normStdDev
# TableCol  7 FieldName Intensity normStdDev
# TableCol  7 Units     MR
# TableCol  8 ColHeader normMin
# TableCol  8 FieldName Intensity normMin
# TableCol  8 Units     MR
# TableCol  9 ColHeader normMax
# TableCol  9 FieldName Intensity normMax
# TableCol  9 Units     MR
# TableCol 10 ColHeader normRange
# TableCol 10 FieldName Intensity normRange
# TableCol 10 Units     MR
# NRows 45 
# NTableCols 10 
# ColHeaders  Index SegId NVoxels Volume_mm3 StructName normMean normStdDev normMin normMax normRange  
  1   4      6852     7260.4  Left-Lateral-Ventricle            36.0019    11.9944    16.0000    85.0000    69.0000 
  2   5       257      328.8  Left-Inf-Lat-Vent                 55.5058     9.8354    22.0000    88.0000    66.0000 
  3   7     15143    15593.6  Left-Cerebellum-White-Matter      88.5000     6.2780    38.0000   104.0000    66.0000 
  4   8     61301    60538.4  Left-Cerebellum-Cortex            73.6324    10.6985     6.0000   140.0000   134.0000 
  5  10      8449     8080.4  Left-Thalamus-Proper              87.9671     8.3555    35.0000   110.0000    75.0000 
  6  11      3142     3040.2  Left-Caudate                      78.3740     7.5265    48.0000   102.0000    54.0000 
  7  12      5425     5274.3  Left-Putamen                      86.4428     5.7711    57.0000   106.0000    49.0000 
  8  13      2017     2016.4  Left-Pallidum                     96.4447     3.6342    75.0000   107.0000    32.0000 
  9  14      1051     1073.5  3rd-Ventricle                     43.6946    14.3018    17.0000    78.0000    61.0000 
 10  15      1525     1673.0  4th-Ventricle                     36.8007    11.3505    18.0000    84.0000    66.0000 
 11  16     23805    23327.6  Brain-Stem                        82.9749     8.3897    30.0000   102.0000    72.0000 
 12  17      4368     4250.0  Left-Hippocampus                  75.4716     7.3720    43.0000   104.0000    61.0000 
 13  18      1590     1546.3  Left-Amygdala                     74.8950     5.9385    44.0000    99.0000    55.0000 
 14  24       993      975.5  CSF                               52.2870    12.2449    26.0000    98.0000    72.0000 
 15  26       566      585.4  Left-Accumbens-area               73.6484     4.3577    50.0000    92.0000    42.0000 
 16  28      4988     4787.1  Left-VentralDC                    88.7536     9.8029    34.0000   107.0000    73.0000 
 17  30        24       41.1  Left-vessel                       59.5000     6.2554    44.0000    74.0000    30.0000 
 18  31       657      596.5  Left-choroid-plexus               51.8630    11.0620    28.0000    81.0000    53.0000 
 19  43      6460     6665.8  Right-Lateral-Ventricle           39.4337    12.4180    15.0000    90.0000    75.0000 
 20  44       193      239.2  Right-Inf-Lat-Vent                48.9223    11.0175    26.0000    82.0000    56.0000 
 21  46     15472    15474.6  Right-Cerebellum-White-Matter     84.3709     8.0148    26.0000   102.0000    76.0000 
 22  47     65751    65152.8  Right-Cerebellum-Cortex           72.8820    11.8809    20.0000   138.0000   118.0000 
 23  49      8771     8361.8  Right-Thalamus-Proper             87.1512     8.7933    30.0000   105.0000    75.0000 
 24  50      3152     3009.0  Right-Caudate                     80.9137     7.7115    47.0000   102.0000    55.0000 
 25  51      4853     4894.8  Right-Putamen                     84.8354     5.7319    51.0000   103.0000    52.0000 
 26  52      2153     2042.2  Right-Pallidum                    93.9145     4.2542    54.0000   105.0000    51.0000 
 27  53      4503     4414.1  Right-Hippocampus                 75.1397     7.3244    39.0000   102.0000    63.0000 
 28  54      1519     1498.2  Right-Amygdala                    75.4924     5.4002    51.0000    93.0000    42.0000 
 29  58       599      585.9  Right-Accumbens-area              76.0067     4.3593    63.0000    98.0000    35.0000 
 30  60      4915     4666.9  Right-VentralDC                   88.1034     9.8386    33.0000   104.0000    71.0000 
 31  62         5       12.4  Right-vessel                      53.0000     5.8737    46.0000    59.0000    13.0000 
 32  63       434      426.3  Right-choroid-plexus              56.0392     9.7654    30.0000    83.0000    53.0000 
 33  72         0        0.0  5th-Ventricle                      0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000 
 34  77       785      720.6  WM-hypointensities                71.3465    11.1410    34.0000   110.0000    76.0000 
 35  78         0        0.0  Left-WM-hypointensities            0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000 
 36  79         0        0.0  Right-WM-hypointensities           0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000 
 37  80         0        0.0  non-WM-hypointensities             0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000 
 38  81         0        0.0  Left-non-WM-hypointensities        0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000 
 39  82         0        0.0  Right-non-WM-hypointensities       0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000 
 40  85       262      269.8  Optic-Chiasm                      77.7366    15.2819    33.0000   100.0000    67.0000 
 41 251      1127     1033.2  CC_Posterior                      96.1003    15.1243    40.0000   110.0000    70.0000 
 42 252       634      563.5  CC_Mid_Posterior                  91.9196    14.4353    35.0000   106.0000    71.0000 
 43 253       970      904.6  CC_Central                        93.2072    12.9240    43.0000   107.0000    64.0000 
 44 254       917      806.9  CC_Mid_Anterior                   91.3719    15.3462    45.0000   109.0000    64.0000 
 45 255      1207     1138.2  CC_Anterior                       99.4341    13.0948    30.0000   117.0000    87.0000
```

I tried converting the text file to a list, but this converts the whole file and I only need the table on the end of the file.

Comment: So the 1st row should be `7260.4  Left-Lateral-Ventricle ` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) function with specific parameters to capture the needed columns into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_table(test_txt, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, comment='#',
                   usecols=[3, 4], names=['Volume_mm3', 'StructName'])
print(df)
```

---

```
    Volume_mm3                     StructName
0       7260.4         Left-Lateral-Ventricle
1        328.8              Left-Inf-Lat-Vent
2      15593.6   Left-Cerebellum-White-Matter
3      60538.4         Left-Cerebellum-Cortex
4       8080.4           Left-Thalamus-Proper
5       3040.2                   Left-Caudate
6       5274.3                   Left-Putamen
7       2016.4                  Left-Pallidum
8       1073.5                  3rd-Ventricle
9       1673.0                  4th-Ventricle
10     23327.6                     Brain-Stem
11      4250.0               Left-Hippocampus
12      1546.3                  Left-Amygdala
13       975.5                            CSF
14       585.4            Left-Accumbens-area
15      4787.1                 Left-VentralDC
16        41.1                    Left-vessel
17       596.5            Left-choroid-plexus
18      6665.8        Right-Lateral-Ventricle
19       239.2             Right-Inf-Lat-Vent
20     15474.6  Right-Cerebellum-White-Matter
21     65152.8        Right-Cerebellum-Cortex
22      8361.8          Right-Thalamus-Proper
23      3009.0                  Right-Caudate
24      4894.8                  Right-Putamen
25      2042.2                 Right-Pallidum
26      4414.1              Right-Hippocampus
27      1498.2                 Right-Amygdala
28       585.9           Right-Accumbens-area
29      4666.9                Right-VentralDC
30        12.4                   Right-vessel
31       426.3           Right-choroid-plexus
32         0.0                  5th-Ventricle
33       720.6             WM-hypointensities
34         0.0        Left-WM-hypointensities
35         0.0       Right-WM-hypointensities
36         0.0         non-WM-hypointensities
37         0.0    Left-non-WM-hypointensities
38         0.0   Right-non-WM-hypointensities
39       269.8                   Optic-Chiasm
40      1033.2                   CC_Posterior
41       563.5               CC_Mid_Posterior
42       904.6                     CC_Central
43       806.9                CC_Mid_Anterior
44      1138.2                    CC_Anterior
```